# В терминале отключить дополнительную информацию о файле

Tags: unix, консоль

я новичок в работе с терминалом, поэтому вопрос может показаться глупым.

Как отключить дополнительную информацию о файле когда я его открываю через cat  или nano

Ниже видно что я имею ввиду, есть файлик, в котором текст просто 15 цифр, но когда я его открываю я вижу дополнительную информацию о файле

> cat testfile.txt

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf600
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 one\
two\
three\
four\
five\
six\
seven\
eight\
nine\
teneleven\
twelve\
thirteen\
fourteen\
fifteen\
}%
```

Comment: Файл в каком редакторе создавали? Выглядит как rtf с расширением .тхт

Comment: попробуйте создать в `nano` новый файл и покажите вывод `cat`

Comment: Спасибо, проблема как раз таки и была в редакторе, он сохранял в формате rtf

Comment: хозяйке на заметку: `file testfile.txt` выведет тип файла